# proof of $a ≡_n b → a^2 ≡_n b^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$a ≡_n b$ can be written as $a = nq_1 + r$ and $b = nq_2 + r$ where the remainders $r$ are the same.

Prove that for n bigger or equal to 2

∀a ∈ N, ∀b ∈ N, $a ≡_n b → a^2 ≡_n b^2$ and therefore

$a ≡_n b → a^m ≡_n b^m$ where ∀m ∈ N

Where do I begin to prove this? Do I use induction?

Comment: Use binomial theoerm.

Comment: Just do it.  $a = nk + r; b = nj + r$ so $a^2 = n^2k^2 + 2nkr + r^2; b^2 = n^2j^2 + 2njr + r^2$.  Do those both have the same remainder?

Comment: If your question is just "how do I prove ...", please do not tag it with the "logic", "proof writing", or "proof verification" tags.  Just tag it according to the area of mathematics of the question.

Answer (score 2):

If $a ≡_n b$ for some $n \geq 2$, then $n |a-b$, thus $n| (a-b)(a+b) = a^2-b^2$. Thus $a^2 ≡_n b^2$.

Comment: then how to prove it for all m

Answer (score 0):

If $a\equiv b$, then $a=nq_1+r$ and $b=nq_2+r$, or $a=nq_1+b-nq_2=n(q_1+q_2)+b$.

Squaring both sides gives $a^2=n^2(q_1+q_2)^2+n(2)(q_1+q_1)(b)+b^2$ which, using the same definition gives $a^2\equiv b^2$.

Comment: could you expand on how you got $a=nq_1+b−nq_2 = n(q_1+q_2)+b $?

Comment: substitute $r$ for $b-nq_2$